# How do we implement in app purchase in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, paypal, webbrowser-control, windows-phone-7.1

Hi i am creating a windows phone 7.1 application, which requires in app purchases

As WP7 does not have a specific in app purchase SDK like iphone does, can we use `paypal` for in app purchases,

I am new to windows phone 7 and paypal API

like open a mobile paypal site in `browsercontrol` when i click on payment button and get the payment done by the user and if the payment success return success message or if fail return failure message.

i do not think `Movend` is a best option, as we have to maintain products database in their website also which i don't want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is answer for my question

Paypal does not have specific sdk for WP7, so i tried to solve above the problem in following way

1. Create a website which will take item prices/details in querystring
2. implement ExpressCheckout in that website only. I've implemented using paypal [Sandbox Web service](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl)
3. Place a browser control in the WP7 app and add an event `BrowserControl_Navigated` for that control
4. Create the Url for for our own website like `string.Format("http://localhost:62744/PaymentGateway/ExpressCheckout.aspx?ItemName={0}&Number={1}&Desc={2}&ItemPrice={3}&ItemUrl={4}", ItemName, ItemNumber, ItemDescription, ItemPrice, ItemUrl).Replace(" ", "+");`
5. Call the Website in our WP7 app code `BrowserControl.Navigate(new Uri(url));`
6. After completion of the payment paypal service will redirect the app to a success url which we mentioned otherwise redirect to failure url
7. in the `BrowserControl_Navigated` event add conditions to check the paypal success and failure urls
8. if the condition success navigate to success page in WP7

   ```
   if (BrowserControl.Source.ToString().Contains( "http://localhost:62744/PaymentGateway/Success.html"))
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Success.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
   ```

### UPDATE:

**Above code will redirect the page to PayPal mobile page, it's not good as iOS login page in look and feel. We can get PayPal iOS page with a small trick in windows phone 7**

By changing the headers(user-agent of client) of the browser will give us the PayPal iPhone page

Like below

```
  string header = "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8B117 Safari/6531.22.7";

  string url = string.Format("http://10.11.32.211:88/PaymentGateway/ExpressCheckout.aspx?ItemName={0}&Number={1}&Desc={2}&ItemPrice={3}&ItemUrl={4}", ItemName, ItemNumber, ItemDescription, ItemPrice, ItemUrl).Replace(" ", "+");

  BrowserControl.IsScriptEnabled = true;

  BrowserControl.Navigate(new Uri(url),null, header);
```

Comment: Hi, I have implemented the payment as you mentioned above, I have website for the products, and that is the website which i access from mobile browser. But my app failed app certification process failure, because of the payment gateway. and i got the following error "the user is prompted for information from with in the app.Transactions must occur external to the app via a secure(HTTPS) website or through a hosted control where the address bar is visible to verify the URL and HTTPS security".  i need to do payment gate way inside my app, can anybody help me to do so.

Comment: Hi, @RVG had you published your app in market place with this payment gateway, is that application certification process succeeded?

Comment: thanks for your reply, had you submitted that app in market place? i have a app with same type of payment gateway, i submitted that app in marketplace, but certification fails.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly acceptable to use PayPal to take payment in your app but be aware of the [Marketplace Application Policy 2.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184841%28v=vs.92%29):

> Your application must be fully functional when acquired from Windows
>   Phone Marketplace (except for additional data as permitted below).
>   Unless you have a pre-existing billing relationship with the user,
>   your application may not require the user to provide payment
>   information, within the application experience, to activate, unlock,
>   or extend usage of the application.

Comment: Code samples for what? Do PayPal not have any tutorials on how to use their API? SO is not intended to be used to get other people to look for tutorials for you.

Comment: It should be highlighted that this only applies to individuals and students (Requirement 2.1.2) and that it's perfectly acceptable for businesses to use third party payment gateways for in-app purchases. The Policy also doesn't state the requirement to use only Microsoft In-App SDK for digital goods (unlocking features, digital content, etc...) as opposed to Apple's stricter policy, however I don't have experience with trying to submit an app which uses In-App SDK other than Microsoft's for content unlocking, etc...

Answer (score 1):

We implemented IAP in our game in March.  We had to trick PayPal into thinking we were an iPhone by modifying the host headers on the initial browser request, in order to get PayPal to recognize the IE9 on the WP as a mobile browser.  It was very painful.  I don't know if they have fixed that yet.

Also, PayPal uses watermarked text boxes, which IE9 does not support, so we needed to include help text on the checkout to show what the unlabeled textboxes were for (for checkout with CC, instead of a PayPal account.

It was a very painful process, but it is working now.  Go download QONQR from the app store and take a look the end result.  Send email to our support address if you want more details on implementation.  Happy to help if you need it.